# Data Oversampling Transceivers

Tags: fpga, dsp, high-speed, transceiver, oversampling

I am trying to find more information about data oversampling for transceivers when grabbing/sending a lower speed signal. I am looking into building a fully compliant HDMI 1.4b fpga core, and have reviewed Xilinx's documents which mention a "40x" oversample for lower speed clock rates. I would like to create the core targeting the GTY or GTX transceiver, and have experience with their design. I have an example for GTH oversampling in xapp1339 (which has apparently disappeared from the internet) but am left confused on the selected frequency "range" for a certain oversample distribution.

What is the theory behind the oversampling of lower clock speeds/data lines for transceiver fpga design? Does the oversampled speed have to be an exact multiple of the speed that is being sampled, or is it okay to be within a certain min+max range? Do you just queue multiple data samples and average?

Any pointers to books, or quick theory answers would be helpful, specifically regarding FPGA design for oversampling.

Comment: I'm not sure that oversampling is *required*. It could be easier to implement since you can oversample the data with any sufficiently fast clock instead of needing to align the clock. It could also be the only way to read a slow signal with a fast transceiver.

Comment: Hello @user253751, I want to support hdmi 1.4b, and eventually extend to a 2.0 core. Due to hdmi's backward compatibility, you'll need to use a transceiver to receive data at 6gbps rate, down to beneath the 2 Gbps rate, at which point the transceiver will need to "oversample" in order to send at that slower rate. This is my confusion, how do you reliably oversample on a transceiver to send at a target bitrate lower than the transceiver speed? Any examples or books on the subject are what I'm looking for.

Comment: For example, if your transceiver can't do 2Gbps, you can send 2Gbps by setting the transceiver to 6Gbps and then sending the same bits 3 times each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With browsing on Xilinx Xapps and with @user253751's comment I was able to find a solution to the sampling/sending on the unsupported lower bandwidth of transceivers.

For TX side, oversampling is very simple -> find the target clock speed, and "oversample" it by choosing a speed an exact multiple of it. Buffer your input to the transceiver module to meet the slow clock rate.

Link: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Serial-Transceivers/7-Series-GTX-minimum-line-rate-workaround/td-p/899989

For Rx side, you must implement a "Non-Integer Data Recovery Unit" or NiDRU, which Xilinx provides multiple Xapps for. Search for xapp875, xapp1240, and xapp1362.